# Salesforce base URL in android REST client

Tags: apex, mobile

I'm building an android application which makes REST callouts to Salesforce. I'm using standard Salesforce REST client, however I need to show a webview in android(Visualforce Page).

How do I hit the URL from the webview? I need a generic method to get the baseURL similar to `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`. Is there one similar to this that I can access from REST client(Android)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you are building a hybrid application built using the Mobile SDK, you can use the following in your the bootconfig.js file:

`var startData = new SFHybridApp.RemoteAppStartData("/apex/BasicVFPage");`

You can read more about this approach in the [Mobile SDK Workbook](http://docs.database.com/dbcom/en-us/mobile_workbook/mobile5_4.htm?version=182.0).

If you are building a native Android app, I remember using this class before the Mobile SDK was introduced. I'm not sure if there's a wrapper for this in the Mobile SDK. If not, you can reuse some code from [this project](http://salesforceandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r114/trunk/SalesforceAndroid/src/com/android/salesforce/web/VisualforceViewer.java).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The class StaticInformation seems to populate the domain. But where do you populate it from?